# Bash kill sleep by parent's PID not working in loop

Tags: bash, loops, sleep, pid, kill

I have a file that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $$ > pid

while true; do
    echo "something"
    sleep 10s
done | lemonbar
```

I want to be able to kill the sleep with a function like this:

```
pkill -P $(cat pid) -f "sleep 10s"
```

The above command works if I move the sleep out of the loop, but with it in the loop it does nothing. What am I missing?

Comment: You identified the parent pid but you didn't tell `pkill` which child process to kill. Try `pkill -P $(<pid) -f sleep`.

Comment: @alvits My bad. I actually did run it with `pkill -P $(cat pid) sleep`. Just forgot that part in the post.

Comment: Note the use of `-f` which you didn't have. It tells `pkill` to match the whole command line instead of just the process name.

Comment: @alvits My full command was `pkill -P $(cat pid) -f "sleep 10s". Sorry for switching so much. I keep trying to fix a mistake and never take the time to do it right.

Comment: And your command works well on my Oracle Enterprise Linux 6.4.

Comment: As @alvits states: in its current form your command should work - as should `pkill -P $(cat pid) sleep` (which should still be robust enough while not having to worry about the specific argument passed to `sleep`). Unless it still doesn't work for you, I suggest you delete this question.

Comment: @mklement0 Tried it again. Still not working. I will have to check on another system.

Comment: That is curious. Are you sure you'r reading the correct `pid` file? What `bash` version and what platform are you on? Are you running the script and the `pkill` command as the same user?

Comment: I know why this isn't working. The process `sleep` isn't a child of the script. It's a grandchild because the while loop is piped `|` to another command. Try `pkill -P $(<pid),$(pgrep -P $(<pid) -d,) sleep` and it should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bash loops start new process id's as a child. The shell variable $PPID should represent the parent PID. However, I read your prior question as well and I think the better question would be what are you really trying to accomplish? All of this smells hacky...

Comment: I am piping the result of the loop to lemonbar. I want it to update every 5 seconds or whenever I click a button on it (which will fire the command to restart the loop).

Comment: @Marcel, in your post it's 10s but you kept saying 5s. Maybe that's the reason the above edits never worked in your case. Maybe you were trying to kill `sleep 10s` but your script is running `sleep 5s`. Because the above code works on my linux.

Comment: @Marcel, note that `pkill "sleep 10s"` will never work without `-f` because `sleep 10s` is not the process name, `sleep` is.

Comment: I have `-f` and I have `sleep 10s`. I accidentally put 5 because I am planning on speeding it up once I get it working.

Comment: It would make more sense to send the pid for each loop to the PID file. $! represents the PID of the last executed command

Comment: @NickBurns: `$!` is the PID of the most recently executed _background_ process.